# excel: highlight similar elements from different excel sheets and copy columns details to that elements

Tags: excel

I have 2 excel sheets:
sheet1: column A and contains X , Y, Z and so on.

sheet2: column A and column B. Column A has some similar elements from sheet1 (e.g. X, Y, Z) and column B contains some attributes: "dog" , "cat" and so on.

In sheet1 I want to Highlight the elements that are in column A in sheet1 and sheet2 and I also want to copy all the attributes from column B (sheet2) to the matching elements in sheet1.

Example below

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaHEk.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjqZX.png)

Thank you !

Comment: "I need..." is not a detailed description of the issue your are facing trying to solve your own problem. You may want to have a look at [ask] a question with an [mcve]. For now I'm sorry but I voted to close your question since it needs more focus.

Comment: So a vlookup is what you need?

Comment: @JvdV . Sorry but i tried to be as specific as I can. I don;t know how to describe my need better than this. I also saw that my question was posted without the first 2 lines and i don't know why. Andreas. I think yes..i am not sure which is the most suitable method.